# PyQt5 QCompleter for QLineEdit crashing with no exception visible

Tags: python, pyqt5, qcompleter

I'm trying to use the QCompleter class for the QLineEdit to give auto completion suggestions while typing, and update the suggestions after the user enters a new text. But when I try to update the Completer with text that starts with something that is already at the completer list, it just crashes the entire app with no visible exception! Even try-except doesn't catch this error, and I can't understand what I am doing wrong...

Below is a simpler example of my code: it is a simple "echo" console application that gets commands from QLineEdit (input text box) and writing it to QTextBrowser (output text box). When entering entirely new "command" (text) it works fine, and being added to the completer, so next time I can see it. But if the new text starts similar to other words in the completer list, choosing it crashes the entire GUI app with no exception visible, not even when I'm running in debug mode...

Please see my example below, and try writing at the upper text box options like: a, aa, aaa (that start similar to completer already word: aaa1)

What am I doing wrong??

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QTextBrowser, QCompleter

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setWindowTitle('console')
        self.setGeometry(10, 50, 500, 800)

        # Create text box for input
        self.consoleCommandLineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.consoleCommandLineEdit.setFixedHeight(25)
        self.consoleCommandLineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.gotConsoleCommand)
        self.completerCommands = ['aaa1','aaa2','aaa3'] # initial completer list
        completer = QCompleter(self.completerCommands)
        self.consoleCommandLineEdit.setCompleter(completer)

        # Create text box for output
        self.consoleViewer = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.consoleViewer.setLineWrapMode(QTextBrowser.NoWrap)

        widget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.vlay = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        self.vlay.addWidget(self.consoleCommandLineEdit)
        self.vlay.addWidget(self.consoleViewer)

    def gotConsoleCommand(self):
        cmd = self.consoleCommandLineEdit.text()
        self.consoleCommandLineEdit.setText('')
        self.sendCommandToConsole(cmd)

    def sendCommandToConsole(self,cmd):
        self.consoleViewer.append(cmd) # add cmd to output box
        if cmd not in self.completerCommands: # if the command is new, add it to the completer
            self.completerCommands.append(cmd)                  # 1. add the new text to the list we have
            completer = QCompleter(self.completerCommands)      # 2. create a new completer object
            self.consoleCommandLineEdit.setCompleter(completer) # 3. set the new completer as the LineEdit completer


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not yet found the cause of the problem but a better solution than creating a new QCompleter every time you need to add a new text. In this case it is better to use a model to store the texts that is the basis of the QCompleter information.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QMainWindow,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QLineEdit,
    QTextBrowser,
    QCompleter,
)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle("console")
        self.setGeometry(10, 50, 500, 800)

        # Create text box for input
        self.consoleCommandLineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.consoleCommandLineEdit.setFixedHeight(25)
        self.consoleCommandLineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.gotConsoleCommand)

        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.model.appendRow([QStandardItem(text) for text in ("aaa1", "aaa2", "aaa3")])
        completer = QCompleter(self.model, self)
        self.consoleCommandLineEdit.setCompleter(completer)

        # Create text box for output
        self.consoleViewer = QTextBrowser(lineWrapMode=QTextBrowser.NoWrap)

        widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        vlay = QVBoxLayout(widget)
        vlay.addWidget(self.consoleCommandLineEdit)
        vlay.addWidget(self.consoleViewer)

    def gotConsoleCommand(self):
        cmd = self.consoleCommandLineEdit.text()
        self.consoleCommandLineEdit.clear()
        self.sendCommandToConsole(cmd)

    def sendCommandToConsole(self, cmd):
        self.consoleViewer.append(cmd)  # add cmd to output box
        if not self.model.findItems(cmd):
            self.model.appendRow(QStandardItem(cmd))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Perhaps something that helps us understand the problem is that if you add a parent to QCompleter the problem does not happen:

```
completer = QCompleter(self.completerCommands, self)
```

but I stress: the best solution is to use a model.

Comment: The problem is related to the popup view: if the completion mode is set to inline, it works fine. Some item view operations are delayed for visual laying out and animations (see the `executePostedLayout` calls in QAbstractItemView sources); after setting the new completer, the old one (and its model) is garbage collected since there's no parent or other python reference, but the view is still trying to update itself, hence (I believe) the crash.

Comment: @musicamante You were suspecting it, an imperfect memory sync

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc! Your solution works perfectly!
I'll adopt your approach.
I didn't know those 'model' objects before, and didn't know how to update the existing Completer.

Comment: BTW, do you know how to clear the QLineEdit after an entry from the completer was selected? When I start typing, and then choose one option from the list (using the down/up arrows) and press ENTER, the text is added to the list below, but still stays in the upper text box... although I run the command:
   self.consoleCommandLineEdit.clear()

Comment: @Koby.G I find your explanation unclear, when do you want it added to the list: when you select an item from the popup and press enter or when you type in the QLineEdit and press enter?

Comment: @eyllanesc, maybe the phrase 'list' is confusing... I'll try to be more precise: After the user chooses an item from the auto-completion (by going down with the arrows, and pressing ENTER) the text is added to the QTextBrowser (i.e. the output text box), which is great, but it also remains at the QLineEdit (i.e. the input text box)... I would like it to be cleared from the QLineEdit (i.e. the input text box) after the user presses ENTER (if the text was not chosen from the auto completion options, the QLineEdit is cleared, and this is what I want also when it is chosen from the auto complete)